# Vector iterator as a function parameter: what's happening in this code?

Tags: c++, iterator

I'd like to know why is this code legal:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator & foo(std::vector<int>::iterator & iter) {
    return ++iter;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4 };

    std::cout << *foo(v.begin()) << std::endl;
}
```

The function accept a **non-const** reference to an iterator, but I have not initialized any variables holding that iterator, I simply passed the result of v.begin() as a reference, but the function is able to increase its value, return it, and use the result to print an element of the vector:

Where is the iterator stored?
I'm still learning C++ (Started around 3 weeks ago) so I'm a bit confused, but I have an "idea":

Is a temporary variable initialized just before the call, like when passing a **literal** to a function that accept a **const** reference (Example below)?

```
std::vector<int>::iterator & foo(std::vector<int>::iterator & iter) {
    return ++iter;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4 };

    std::vector<int>::iterator tempIter = v.begin();
    std::cout << *foo(tempIter) << std::endl;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Uh... `std::vector<int>::iterator tempIter = v.begin();`?

Comment: That is my theory, I think it creates that hidden variables to store the iterator, the real code is the first block

Comment: Which compiler do you use? Both GCC and Clang are giving me an error.

Comment: And Visual Studio 2017 does not accept this code either.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 and using the last version of Visual Studio 2017, and the output is correct, 2...

Comment: 1) Turn on warnings 2) Turn on strict standard conformace. Check if this behavior persist

Comment: Can you tell me how to turn on warnings and strict standard conformace?

Comment: Project - properties - C++ - General - Warning Level - Select Level4  then C++ - Language - Disable Language Extentions - Select Yes